# Sudden error in eclipse when I upgraded my JDK

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, macos-mojave

I upgraded my JDK version from 10 to 11, after this I tried running my programs that I had made on eclipse with the new version.

**Then this happened:**

> "Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
>   java.lang.LayerInstantiationException: Package jdk.internal.jrtfs in both module java.base and module jrt.fs"

Many websites online claimed that it was because I hadn't changed my JDK version in the setup for individual projects but now that I have the issue still persists. Also, I deleted java reinstalled it and deleted eclipse and reinstalled that too. However, i still see no change.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

this is the command line

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -p /Users/mylene1/.p2/pool/plugins/org.junit_4.12.0.v201504281640/junit.jar:/Users/mylene1/.p2/pool/plugins/org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v20180420-1519.jar -classpath /Users/mylene1/eclipse-workspace/Assignment_4/bin HousingApplication

Comment: For Java 11 you need at least Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10). Make sure the JDK is configured in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_.

Comment: I'm on macos mojave and i've got the latest elipse when i reinstalled it, is there a way to check from the terminal?

Comment: _Help > About Eclipse IDE_ shows the version.

Comment: Just checked and it looks like I do have 4.10

Comment: Have you updated _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_ after upgrading from Java 10 to Java 11?

Comment: yeah I changed it to 11

Comment: Can you find out where the module `jrt.fs` comes from? If you cannot find it in the _Package/Project Explorer_ view somewhere below _JRE System Library_, _Referenced Libraries_, etc., the module must be included via the run configuration by mistake.

Comment: I can't see it inside of the JRE System library but I keep seeing module.info, which I though I didn't select. Could this be causing the issue?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Please show a screenshot.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/oS7edtH

Comment: That's correct: since Java 9 there are modules which contain a `module-info.class` in the default package. In the run configuration (_Run > Run Configurations..._) there is a button _Show Command Line_. Please copy the command line and added it to your question.

Comment: If you get the same error when executing the command line command on the command line, your Java installation in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk` is broken. Does uninstalling and reinstalling Java 11 fix your issue?

Comment: It seems it fixed itself when i went in to look at the command line. Thank you so much for your help still though!